# Pass html variable to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, primeng

I am using Angular with PrimeNG for my tabsystem on my web application.
I have the following issue:

```
<div *ngFor="let project of projects">
<div *ngIf="project.id === triggerProjectIdRefresh()">
  <div *ngFor="let dashboard of project.dashboards; trackBy: dashboardTrack()">
    <div *ngIf="dashboard.id === triggerDashboardIdRefresh()" >
      <!--bottom toolbar-->

      <!-- Tab system -->


        <p-tabView id="tabView" [controlClose]="true" (onChange)="setActiveTabDeleteable()" (onClose)="deleteConfirmation(sheet.id)" class="tabGroup" orientation="bottom">
          <div *ngFor="let sheet of dashboard.sheets; trackBy: trackSheet()" > <!-- alluser sheets -->
            <p-tabPanel (mousedown)="tabId(sheet.id)" [header]="sheet.name" *ngIf="sheet.type === 'enduser'" >

              <!--tabbody-->
              <p-card class="middlecardSheet"> <!-- widget field is child of tab-->
                <app-display-widgets style="{border: #7A7A7A 2em solid;}" *ngIf="sheet.id === refreshCurrentSheet()" [dashboardID]="dashboard.id"></app-display-widgets>
              </p-card>

            </p-tabPanel> ...
```

In the `<p-tabView>` element I am setting up a function which is called when the tap is closed. The function needs some further information for background processing, so I am passing the sheet.id. Problem is that because of hierachical structure the sheet is defined one element under. So I tried anyhow to pass the `sheet.id` to the javascript in the `<p-tabPanel>`. I thaught when the panel is clicked I can work with the given `sheet.id` . But any tries I have taken relsuts in no working solution. So my question is, how can I pass the variable `sheet.id` to the javascript or a javascript function?

Comment: Have you tried with the onClose event provided in primeng. Using that you can get the index of the closed tab. May be then you can create custom mechanism to get the sheet.id in your ts file. Anyway it's better to create stackblitz for your code then people can help you.
Here is the primeng stackblitz boilerplate. Import your module and replicate you scenario. https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-select-btn

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass sheet id on click you can do it as:

```
<p-tabPanel (click)="tabId(sheet.id)" [header]="sheet.name" *ngIf="sheet.type === 'enduser'" >
```

Comment: yes, but the click event gets not fired. I guess maybe it gets overwritten because the tab itself is also clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable called **selectedSheetId** and on

```
(mousedown)="selectedSheetId = sheet.id"
```

So that on

```
(onClose)="deleteConfirmation(selectedSheetId)"
```

will work as you expected.

If mousedown is not working on p-tabPanel,

```
<p-tabPanel header="Header 1">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary-live" 
                (click)="selectedSheetId = sheet.id">Click</button>
</p-tabPanel>
```

Or even a Div tag here will be able to help you.

Else you can rely on the index of the p-tabView [activeIndex]="activeTab" and correlated between your sheetId there.

Comment: Also in component ts, declare selectedSheetId.

Comment: the mousedown event is not called on <p-tabPanel>

Comment: the mousedown event is not called on <p-tabPanel>

Comment: by putting elements in <p-tabPanel> you are defining the content of the tab. so this won't help me.